# Cosmosdb Trigger for Azure Functions Application

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

We are developing applications using azure functions (python). I have 2 questions regarding Azure Functions Application

1. Can we monitor 2 collections using single Cosmosdb trigger ? 
   ---  I have looked through the documentation and it seems it doesn't support. Did i miss anything ?
2. If there are 2 functions monitoring the same collection, will only one of the functions be triggered. 
   -- I observed this behaviour today. I was running 2 instances of functions app and the data from cosmosdb trigger was sent to only one of the application. I am trying to find out the reason for it.

Comment: why do you want to different functions to be triggered by the same event (change in your collection)?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
1-I had never used multiple input triggers, but according to the official [wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/function.json) it's possible, just add function.json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "image-resize"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "original",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "images-original/{name}"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "resized",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "images-resized/{name}"
    }
  ]
}
```

PS: I know you're using cosmosDB, the sample above is just to illustrate

2- I assume it's due the way it's implemented (e.g topic vs queue). So the first function lock the event / message, then the second one is not aware of the event. At this moment, Durable Functions for python is still under development and should be released next month [(03/2020)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/227#issuecomment-588579899). It will allow you to chain the execution of the functions just like it's available for c# / node:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp#chaining

What you can do is output to a queue, which will trigger your second function after the first function completes. (pretty much what Durable Functions offers)

Comment: As per the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings.  A trigger defines how a function is invoked and a function must have exactly one trigger. Triggers have associated data, which is often provided as the payload of the function. So, the above example may not work ?

Comment: I've also got the json sample from official doc and as you can see, it has two input triggers